# undefined index

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, banco-de-dados

Olá, estou em um projeto que trabalha com muitos formulários e preciso que quando a pessoa chegue no ultimo formulario, ao clicar em submit ele mande o resultado de uma variável `javascript` para o banco. Vou colocar apenas dois forms para não ficar enorme:

primeiramente minhas funções:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
        var arrayPontos = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ];
        var contador = 0; 

            function zeraCont(){ contador = 0;}


            function contarEscolhas(){
                contador ++; 
                if(contador>3){ 
                        alert('Escolha apenas três opções');
                    //for (i=0;i<document.elements.length;++i){
                    //    if(document.questao.elements[i].type == "checkbox"){document.questao.elements[i].checked=0;}
                    //}
                    contador= 0;
                }
            } 

            function arrayPositionMax(array) {
                var max = -Infinity;
                var position = -Infinity;
                for (i = 0; i != array.length; ++i) {
                    if (array[i] > max) {
                        max = array[i];
                        position = i;
                    }
                }
                return position;
            }
            function getPontos(pontos){
                arrayPontos[pontos]++;
            }      
            function finalizar(){  
                var itens = ["Enfermagem", "Eletroeletronica", "Informatica", "Alimentos", "Plasticos", "Logistica", "Administracao", "Quimica", "Meio_Ambiente", "Mecatronica", "Eletronica", "Telecomunicacao", "Seguranca"];
                var resultado = itens[arrayPositionMax(arrayPontos) - 1];
                return resultado;
                //alert("O resultado do seu teste é: "+resultado+"."); 
            }



            function sendToDB(resultado){ 
                //alert("O resultado do seu teste é: "+resultado+"."); 
                $.ajax({
                    type:'post',        //Definimos o método HTTP usado
                    dataType: 'json',   //Definimos o tipo de retorno
                    url: 'resultadoTeste.php?resultado=' + resultado,//Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
                    success: function(dados){
                        alert('sucesso!');
                    }
                });
            } 
    </script>
```

todos os formulários (com exceção do ultimo) trabalham da seguinte maneira:

```
<form name="questao" method="post" role="login">
                        <section>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                                    <div align = "center">
                                        <br>QUESTÃO 1</br>
                                    </div>
                                    <br> <font size="4,5">Marque três alternativa que expressam o que <b><font color="#f15344">você gostaria de </b></font>trabalhar com:</font></br>

                                    <fieldset name="Q1">
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="1">
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Enfermagem" onclick="getPontos(1);contarEscolhas()"> <font size="4"> Garantir a saúde das pessoas</font></label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="2">
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Eletroeletronica" onclick="getPontos(2);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Máquinas e instalações elétricas</font>
                                        </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="3">
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Informatica" onclick="getPontos(3);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Usar lógica para fazer programas e sistemas</font></label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="4">
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Alimentos" onclick="getPontos(4);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Desenvolver, gerenciar e distribuir produtos</font>
                                          </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="5">
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Plasticos" onclick="getPontos(5);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Desenvolver, gerenciar e distribuir produtos alimenticios</font>
                                          </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="6">
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Logistica" onclick="getPontos(6);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Desenvolver, gerenciar e distribuir produtos plásticos</font>
                                          </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="7">
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Administracao" onclick="getPontos(7);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Gerenciar e influenciar pessoas a atingirem metas</font></label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="8">
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Quimica" onclick="getPontos(8);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Estudar, manusear e transformar substâncias ou materiais </font>
                                          </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="9">
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Meio Ambiente" onclick="getPontos(9);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Estudar, manusear e transformar substâncias ou materiais para beneficiar natureza</font>
                                          </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="10">
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Mecatronica" onclick="getPontos(10);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Projetar, usar, instalar e controlar  máquinas industriais</font>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="11"> 
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Eletronica" onclick="getPontos(11);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Sistemas e aparelhos eletrônicos </font></label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="12"> 
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Telecomunicacao" onclick="getPontos(12);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Sistemas e aparelhos de comunicação</font></label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox" name="Alternativa" value="13">
                                          <label><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Seguranca" onclick="getPontos(13);contarEscolhas()"><font size="4"> Instruir e garantir a segurança das pessoas e locais </font></label>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset><br>
                                    <br>

                                    <div align="right">

                                        <a class="btn btn-laranja" onclick="show('link3');finalizar();zeraCont()">PRÓXIMO</a></br>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>
```

O ultimo form tem um botão chamado resultado no final com o valor de `submit`, mas também executa uma função:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-rosa" value="RESULTADO" onclick="show('link20');sendToDB();">
```

e tem como `action` uma página chamada resultado.php:

```
    <?php
        //Conectando ao banco de dados
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "qct");
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }

        $resultado = $_POST["resultado"];

        //Atualizando banco de dados
        $res = $mysqli->query("UPDATE qct.usuarios SET resultado='".$resultado."' WHERE id=1");  

        //Pais não encontrado
        if (!$res) {
            echo "Query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
            //TODO: devolver um objeto JSON vazio
        }
?>
<html> 
<head> 
</head>

<body> 

  <div id="link20" class="dynamic_link" style="display:none">
            <section class="container">
                <section class="login-form">
                    <form method="post" action="resultado.php"  role="login">
                        <section>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">  

                                    <div align = "center"><font color="#585454">
                                        <br>Seu curso é: <?php echo $resultado ?>


                                        </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </form>
                </section>
            </section>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

A página resultado, deveria exibir o resultado da soma feita na página dos formulários e enviar essa informação para o BD, mas ela exibe a mensagem: 
`Notice: Undefined index: resultado in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sites\TCCBinha\questionario\resultado.php on line 8`.

Percebi que isso pode estar acontecendo justamente porque não estou enviando o resultado atravez do ajax como deveria.

Então a minha dúvida é se existe como eu passar o valor da variável resultado que foi criada na função `finalizar()` para o meu ajax que está em `sendToDB`. Obrigada

Comment: Você não faz post de resultado em momento nenhum, não tem como recuperar este valor. Se quer pegar com post, tem que enviar com post, mesmo que seja por Ajax. Não adianta mandar como variável de URL: `url: 'resultadoTeste.php?resultado=` - para pegar assim, só com `$_GET`.

Comment: veja aqui exemplos de como fazer um POST com jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/